# Flutter issues with Android Firebase dependencies after Dependency Upgrades

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, gradle, dependencies

i recently decided to upgrade my Flutter dependencies and pubspec.yaml all to newest versions according to pub.dev.

As i mainly tested with iOS i just realised pretty late, that my android build did not work any longer. The Error Message unfortunately was very low on direct information.

```
Gradle sync failed: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
            Problems reading data from Binary store in /private/var/folders/mw/s9362rr10qv43x_yh6qgm17w0000gn/T/gradle8805841490318013448.bin offset 286370 exists? true
            Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (25 s 303 ms)
```

I however decided to also provide my android studio an update to 4.1 and upgraded also the gradle dependencies.

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2' // 3.5.1
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4' // 4.3.3
}
```

The new attempt in android studio was providing a more relatable error in reference to Firebase

```
Gradle sync failed: Problems reading data from Binary store in /private/var/folders/mw/s9362rr10qv43x_yh6qgm17w0000gn/T/gradle1329056569736096566.bin offset 296201 exists? true
                Corrupt serialized resolution result. Cannot find selected module (224) for constraint platform-runtime -> com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:21.0.1
                Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (10 m 18 s 294 ms)
```

My Flutter Doctor -v gives me confidence that everything is fine. (the Plugin Errors are an existing and known issue by the Flutter team with Android Studio 4.1 and not related)

```
    [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.6, on macOS 11.1 20C69 darwin-x64, locale de-DE)
    • Flutter version 1.22.6 at /Users/kaibaier/development/flutter
    • Framework revision 9b2d32b605 (5 days ago), 2021-01-22 14:36:39 -0800
    • Engine revision 2f0af37152
    • Dart version 2.10.5
    • Pub download mirror https://pub.flutter-io.cn
    • Flutter download mirror https://storage.flutter-io.cn

 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/kaibaier/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.2
    • ANDROID_HOME = /Users/kaibaier/Library/Android/sdk
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.4)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.4, Build version 12D4e
    • CocoaPods version 1.9.3

[!] Android Studio (version 4.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.52.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.18.1

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • Redmi Note 8 (mobile) • 18d3ce30 • android-arm64 • Android 10 (API 29)
```

For the sake of completion i also add the pubspec.yaml dependencieswith the previous used Version. You will notice the big Version jump in Firebase and Google Maps

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  permission_handler: ^5.0.1+1
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0 #^0.1.3
  firebase_core: ^0.7.0 # ^0.5.0 
  firebase_auth: ^0.20.0+1 # ^0.18.0+1
  firebase_storage: ^7.0.0 # ^4.0.0
  cloud_firestore: ^0.16.0 #^0.14.0+2
  provider: ^4.3.3 #^4.3.2
  flutter_spinkit: ^4.1.2+1
  flutter_vector_icons: ^0.2.1
  intl: ^0.16.1
  image_cropper: ^1.3.1
  image_picker: ^0.6.7+21 #^0.6.7+11
  searchable_dropdown: ^1.1.3
  flutter_colorpicker: ^0.3.5 #^0.3.4
  flutter_masked_text: ^0.8.0
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.12+4 #^0.5.8
  path_provider: ^1.6.27 #^1.6.11
  location: ^3.2.4 #^3.0.2
  table_calendar: ^2.3.3 #^2.2.3
  url_launcher: ^5.7.10 #^5.6.0
  google_maps_flutter: ^1.1.1 #^0.5.32
  flutter_google_places: ^0.2.6
  http: ^0.12.2 #^0.12.1
  uuid: ^2.2.2 #^2.0.4
  flutter_appcenter_bundle: ^3.2.0+2
  preload_page_view: ^0.1.4
  device_preview: ^0.5.5 #^0.4.8
  wakelock: ^0.2.1+1 #^0.1.4+2
```

Any help / ideas or thoughts are very welcome :)

UPDATE:
After trying to run the Test again on my android phone i run into another related error.

```
    Note: /Users/kaibaier/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-0.7.0/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/core/FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Problems reading data from Binary store in /private/var/folders/mw/s9362rr10qv43x_yh6qgm17w0000gn/T/gradle3299415366350440389.bin offset 0 exists? true

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

UPDATE #2:
I also posted the issue over here in GitHub
https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/4848

UPDATE #3:
Ok i was able to figure out that this file: /private/var/folders/mw/s9362rr10qv43x_yh6qgm17w0000gn/T/gradle3299415366350440389.bin
only exists during a build phase. After the error is thrown, it is directly gone again.

Update #4:
I rolled back to the old firebase dependencies for now. Just upgraded the firebase storage. All runs smoothly after some pod and Grasflecks clean.
My issue still exists, as I hope to get back to the new versions of firebase dependencies . But for now I can build again .

Comment: did you try cleaning the gradle files ./gradlew clean

Comment: Hi, just tried error remains Corrupt serialized resolution result. Cannot find selected module (212) for constraint platform-runtime -> com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:21.0.1

Comment: For ios try doing: `pod deintegrate`, `pod cache clean --all` and `rm Podfile.lock`

Comment: iOS is working fine

Comment: could you tell me the gradle version and java version?

Comment: use ./gradlew --version

Comment: Sorry for the late reply here it is Gradle 6.5.1 / Kotlin 1.3.72 / Groovy 2.5.11 does this help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had exactly the same issue after a firebase upgrade. Along with pubspec.yaml There is another (somewhat hidden) dependency you need to upgrade in app/build.gradle. I changed mine from 17.x to this and all builds and runs.

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:18.0.2'